# How to filter by property name inside controller in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is what I did so far:

```
 fourHunderds = $filter('filter')($scope.filterErrors, {StatusCode:"404"}).length;
```

`$scope.filterErrors` has `StatusCode` property but it seems length of the `$scope.filterErrors` and `fourHunders` are always the same (filtering is not working, this line of code doesn't work for me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are using a predefined angular filter you can do this with **[Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**

```
fourHunderds = $scope.filterErrors.filter(function(item){
                   return item.StatusCode == '404';
               }).length
```